# Is the empty set a vector in every vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A vector space consists of a nonempty set V of objects. 
According to set theory, every set must contain the empty set.
So I deduce that the empty set is a member of every vector space.
But is the empty set also a vector in the vector space?

Comment: "According to set theory, every set must contain the empty set. So I deduce that the empty set is a member of every vector space." This is false. The empty set is a *subset* of every set. But it is not an *element* of every set.

Comment: The empty set is a subset of the underlying set of the vector space. The empty set *itself* is not a vector. Though, are you confusing the empty set with the $\bf{0}$ vector? A vector space must contain an *identity* so every vector space with addition must contain the zero vector. Edited, it made no sense before.

Comment: @Rahul: You may consider making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the empty set need not be an element of a given vector space. However there is a class of interesting cases where it is: the power set of any set is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$ where the addition operation is symmetric difference, so
$$A+B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$$
In this case the empty set is the zero vector.